# Text Area Form Field With Word Processing Tools

Tags: forms, textarea

I have a form on my site that allows users to enter and submit their poetry. I am wondering if there is a code or plug-in that gives that 'text-area' form field some basic word processing tools, such as; Spell Check, Bold or Italicized font, Indentation, etc...

Comment: Search Keyword : Web WYSIWYG Editor

Answer (score 0):

You can try out ckeditor which is an advanced textarea plugin supporting all languages. Its has most features like word.